# OutKind.ConsoleApplication Err(Roslyn Compiler)

Tags: compiler-errors, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis, roslyn-project-system

> I compiling with roslyn some Diagnostics Error showing My code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Loader;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;

namespace RoslynTest
{
    public class Test
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             const string code =@"using System;
namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(""Hello, World!"");
        }
    }
}";

        var tree = SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(code);
            var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("HelloWorldCompiled.exe", options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.ConsoleApplication),
                syntaxTrees: new[] { tree }, references: new[] { MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location) });
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var compileResult = compilation.Emit(stream);
                var assembly = Assembly.Load(stream.GetBuffer());
                assembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static, null, new object[] { null }, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Err Coming this line:--> var compileResult = compilation.Emit(stream);
>   Err is: The name 'Console' doesn't exist in current context.(Diagnostics Err)
>   how to solve this err

Comment: What runtime and compiler library versions are you using?

Comment: .NetCore 3.1 , Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp(3.6.0)  and System.Runtime.Loader(4.3.0)

Comment: See if this helps: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/wiki/Runtime-code-generation-using-Roslyn-compilations-in-.NET-Core-App.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Console` type is located in `System.Console.dll`

**typeof(Console).Assembly.Location** -> `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\...\System.Console.dll`

This can be fixed by using the correct references:

```
var runtimeDir = System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory();
var tree = SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(code);
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("HelloWorldCompiled", 
    options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.ConsoleApplication),
    syntaxTrees: new[] { tree },
    references: new[]
    {
        MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),
        MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(runtimeDir, "System.Console.dll")),
        MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(runtimeDir, "System.Runtime.dll"))
    });
```

Comment: Hi @karthick19892089. Does this answer your question? :)

Comment: In order to help other users which have similar problems you can accept the solution. This will also save other people time since it will mark the question as answered.